# Cant get Rect.intersects(rec, rec2) to work

Tags: java, android, rect

For some reason my program won't get through `Rect.intersects(re,hitcore)`. If I use `System.out.println()re.flattenToString()`, I see that the two rectangles intersect but it won't `return true`.

I also tried using `re.intersect(hitcore)`, but still nothing. Help?

```
import android.graphics.Rect;   

public class Enemy {
public Rect re, hitCore;

private boolean hit = false;


public Enemy() {
    re = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    hitCore = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);

}

public void update() {

    re.set(centerX + leftX, centerY + topY, rightX, botY); // these are set by another class                  
    hitCore.set(ship.getCenterX() + 3, ship.getCenterY() + 10, 93, 20);

            //System.out.println(re.flattenToString() + " rect1");
    //System.out.println(hitCore.flattenToString() + " rect2");

    checkHit(hitCore);

}

private void checkHit(Rect hitCore) {
    if (Rect.intersects(hitCore, re)) {
        hit = true;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I was setting up rectangle using x,y and width,height.  The actual parameters are the top left corner coordinate and bottom right corner coordinate.

```
 rect.set(x1,y1,x2,y2);
```