# Rect.intersects() is not working correctly

Tags: java, android

I have an ArrayList called rectangles that are at specific x,y,width,height values and another Rect called bar that moves up the screen and is supposed to intersect those rectangles. This is my code:

```
for (Rect rect : rectangles) {
   if(Rect.intersects(bar, rect)) {
       Log.d("GameScreen", "intersected");
    intersected = rect;
    checkButtons();

  }
}
```

However, when I look at my logcat, it isn't logging "GameScreen, intersected" and the counter I have set up from checkButtons() doesn't change the score on the screen when they intersect and bar just seems to pass through the rectangles.

How can I make it so that I am sure that the Rects are intersecting?

Comment: Here is [another Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645490/cant-get-rect-intersectsrec-rec2-to-work?rq=1) with a similar problem. That solution may fit here, too :)

Comment: See constructor: [`Rect(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#Rect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). It's not `x, y, width, height`.

Comment: OK I worded that wrong. This is what all my rectangles look like: `rectangles.add(new Rect(135,614,160,588));`